# IdleStateHandler is not triggering IdleStateEvent since 3.5.9.Final (3.x)

Tags: netty

I am trying to close an idle connection from netty server, after the idle timeout period, using IdleStateHandler, similar to http://netty.io/3.9/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateHandler.html.
Some how it doesn't work for me. Debugged the issue and figured out that the Timer is actually triggering the "IdleStateEvent" event once it timeout, it get lost from "IdleStateHandler.fireChannelIdle" method after it is added to the queue "AbstractNioSelector.taskQueue". It is introduced in 3.5.9.Final, but works fine if i use netty 3.5.8.Final version.

I am tied to netty 3.9.x version, using 3.9.4.Final now.

Affected versions : 3.5.9.Final to 3.9.5.Final

How to reproduce this.
The following code closes the idle connection after 1 minute, if i use netty 3.5.8.Final, but any higher 3.x library can't do that.

```
public class PipelineFactory implements ChannelPipelineFactory {
  ...
  public PipelineFactory(Timer timer) {
    this.timer = timer;
    this.chHandler = new EchoServerHandler();
  }

  @Override
  public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
   final ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline(new IdleStateHandler(this.timer, 0, 0, 60),
           new MyIdleStateAwareHandler());
    pipeline.addLast("handler", chHandler);
    return pipeline;
  }
}

class MyIdleStateAwareHandler extends IdleStateAwareChannelHandler {
  ...
  @Override
  public void channelIdle(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, IdleStateEvent e) {
    if (e.getState() == IdleState.ALL_IDLE) {
      logger.info("Closed idle socket.");
      e.getChannel().close();
    }
  }
}

class EchoServerHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {
  ...
  @Override
  public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(600000);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException iex) {
      logger.error("interrupted " + iex.getMessage());
    }

    ChannelBuffer buffer = (ChannelBuffer) e.getMessage();
    while(buffer.readable()) {
      System.out.print((char) buffer.readByte());
      System.out.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Really appreciate any help or pointers to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please open a bug-report on the issue tracker. Thanks!